# correcting the rectangular mask for any tilt using opencv

Tags: python, opencv, image-rotation, affinetransform

I have to extract a rectangular object from a grayscale image. I am using thresholding to extract rectangular mask as shown below

[image]

Sometimes, the rectangular object may have tilts as shown above. In the next step, I have to correct the shape of rectangular object to get the following output (roughly)

[image]

At the moment, I am using Hough Line transform to find the line closest to the image edge (i.e. left most line vertical line). I get the angle of the line and use that angle to get the rotation matrix and perform warpAffine on the whole image (using opencv functions).

Vertical line detection near to image edge
[image]

Affine corrected image
[image]

I am using the following code in python

```js
# get the rotation matrix
myRotMatrix = cv2.getRotationMatrix2D((inBinaryImage.shape[1]/2,inBinaryImage.shape[0]/2),-myAngle,1)            
 
# perform warpAffine to avoid issues            
myBinaryImageTemp = cv2.warpAffine(inBinaryImage,myRotMatrix,(myNewWidth,myNewHeight))
```

As you can see that affine corrected object still has some tilt on the top and the bottom. Is there an easy way to also remove tilt from the top/bottom ??

Thanks

Comment: Your issue is that the rectangle itself is not actually a rectangle, it is a parrellogram. Its sides while parrallel, are not possessing a right angle. The code is functioning properly in this cases where it is rotating the correct amount, but the "shape"'s corners connecting to that line are roughly 108 degrees and 80 degrees for the bottom and top corner. (This is what results in your tilt.)

Comment: is there a way it can be fixed ??

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to do something with `getPerspectiveTransform`, I used it [in a grid finder](https://github.com/JulienPalard/grid-finder/blob/master/grid_finder.py#L407), my usage is not really the exact same as yours, but you can certainly learn enough by reading it. I'm no opencv expert, don't expect state-of-the-art code.

Also, it's probably near-to-impossible to know the ratio of the tilted object, without using fancy thinks like supervised learning to understand the orientation of the object. There's a discussion about it here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1339924/compute-ratio-of-a-rectangle-seen-from-an-unknown-perspective